# Sverchok text nodes, multi line text out with line break, how?

Tags: node-editor, sverchok

i am using the last release of **Sverchok nodes 1.2.0**, joining texts (strings) but i cant make a multi-lines output. What node should i use here to get a line break between 2 text contents?

[image: sverchok text nodes to create 2 lines output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one possible way would be like this:

[image]

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: yes, this is it, using list node makes it multi lines text output, thanks